# How to bring the SelectedItem in a combobox to be shown in the page?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I have a ComboBox defined like this:

```
                   <ComboBox
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Heights}"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    PlaceholderText=""
                    SelectedValuePath="Cm"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedHeightValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    FontSize="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource LightFontFamily}"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource TrendsTitleForegroundBrush}"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    RequestedTheme="Light"
                    Margin="-7,-10,10,0">

                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                       FontSize="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}"
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource LightFontFamily}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

The ComboBox has more items than the screen can display at once. The SelectedValue is correct, i.e. it is colored blue. But the item might not be shown on the page and the user has to scroll to reach it. Can the ComboBox be forced to show that item and make it visible to the user?

Thanks